# How to use oracle wallet

Tags: oracle

I am trying to store password in an Oracle Wallet file which I will retrieve from the code and use.

I tried to create a wallet and save a credential there:-

```
$ mkstore -wrl <wallet_location> -createCredential sid scott tiger

Oracle Secret Store Tool : Version 12.1.0.2
Copyright (c) 2004, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Enter wallet password:   
Create credential oracle.security.client.connect_string1
```

The creation does not give any error but when I try to list the credential, I don’t get anything.

```
$ mkstore -wrl -listCredential

Oracle Secret Store Tool : Version 12.1.0.2
Copyright (c) 2004, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved
```

Also, how to retrieve this password using java?

Comment: I found the answer to the first part :-

Answer (score 12):

For connecting the Oracle DB using wallet requires the following changes.

1. You need to create a wallet store, you need to also choose a password for the wallet and you need to use this password while modifying the wallet.

`<OracleClientHome>/bin/mkstore -wrl <Where you want to store your wallet> -create`

**e.g.** `C:\Oracle_11.2.0\product\client_1\bin\mkstore -wrl C:\Users\sample\app\wallet`

2. You need to add the TNS entries in `tnsnames.ora`
   `<OracleClientHome>/network/admin/tnsnames.ora`

   The same TNS entry name will be used us wallet connect string.

```
<TNS_Entry_Name> =
  (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS =
    (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <Hostname>)(PORT = <Port_Number>)) 
  (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = dedicated)(SERVICE_NAME = <Service_Name>))
  )
```

**e.g.**

```
MY_FAVORITE_SERVER =
  (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS =
    (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myfavoriteserver.net)(PORT = 123)) 
  (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = dedicated)(SERVICE_NAME = myfavoriteserver))
  )
```

3. You need to create wallet entry for the above TNS entry with credentials. You also need to provide the wallet password which you have given while creating the wallet.

```
<OracleClientHome>/bin/mkstore -wrl <Where you want to store your wallet> -createCredential <TNS_Entry_Name/Wallet_Entry_name> <DB_Username> <DB_Password>
```

**e.g.**

```
C:\Oracle_11.2.0\product\client_1\bin\mkstore -wrl C:\Users\sample\app\wallet -createCredential MY_FAVORITE_SERVER john password123
```

4. You need to add the `sqlnet.ora` file to update the wallet location and wallet override flag to true.

```
WALLET_LOCATION = 
  (SOURCE = (METHOD = FILE)
    (METHOD_DATA = (DIRECTORY = <Where you want to store your wallet>))
  )

SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE = TRUE
```

**e.g.**

```
WALLET_LOCATION = 
  (SOURCE = (METHOD = FILE)
    (METHOD_DATA = (DIRECTORY = C:\Users\sample\app\wallet))
  )

SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE = TRUE
```

5. Test the DB connection using wallet and Oracle client to make sure the wallet configurations are correct.

```
<OracleClientHome>/bin/sqlplus /nolog
```

```
SQL> connect <DB_Username>/<DB_Password>@<TNS_Entry_Name>
```

```
SQL> connect /@<TNS_Entry_Name>
```

**e.g.**

```
SQL> connect john/password123@MY_FAVORITE_SERVER
```

```
SQL> connect /@MY_FAVORITE_SERVER
```

6. You need to make the Java application ready to use the wallet and run the Java program with the below JVM Parameters.

- Add the following jars to the application classpath:

```
<OracleClientHome>/jdbc/lib/ojdbc.jar
<OracleClientHome>/jlib/oraclepki.jar
<OracleClientHome>/jlib/osdt_cert.jar
<OracleClientHome>/jlib/osdt_core.jar
```

**e.g.**

```
C:\Oracle_11.2.0\product\client_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc.jar C:\Oracle_11.2.0\product\client_1\jlib\oraclepki.jar
C:\Oracle_11.2.0\product\client_1\jlib\osdt_cert.jar
C:\Oracle_11.2.0\product\client_1\jlib\osdt_core.jar
```

Change application configuration thin url to use the wallet:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:/@<TNS_Entry_Name/Wallet_Entry_name>
```

**e.g.**

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:/@MY_FAVORITE_SERVER
```

- Also add the following properties as JVM Parameters, this help the library to find the oracle wallet

```
-Doracle.net.tns_admin=<OracleClientHome>/network/admin -Doracle.net.wallet_location=<Where you want to store your wallet>
```

**e.g.**

```
-Doracle.net.tns_admin=C:\Oracle_11.2.0\product\client_1\network\admin -Doracle.net.wallet_location=C:\Users\sample\app\wallet
```

**You are all set!!**

- For listing the existing credentials in the wallet you can use the below command, but you need to provide the wallet password which you have given while creating the wallet.

```
<OracleClientHome>/bin/mkstore -wrl <Where you want to store your wallet> -listCredential
```

**e.g.**

```
C:\Oracle_11.2.0\product\client_1\bin\mkstore -wrl C:\Users\sample\app\wallet -listCredential
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! As a bonus, I saw it was authored by a familiar face. Hope you're doing well and thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

One important thing you must have in mind is, that the alias you choose for the `createCredential` command must be *identical* to the URL you are using for the connection.

When your JDBC connection string looks like `jdbc:oracle:thin:/@dbsrv:1521/orcl` you must use the command

```
mkstore -wlr /foobar -createCredential dbsrv:1521/orcl USER PASSWORD
```