# Java JDBC and Oracle Wallet Connection

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, wallet

[How to use oracle wallet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160428/how-to-use-oracle-wallet?newreg=c8f5547f7cc744feb6aa74db78f48d3c)

Using this as reference. I am still unable to connect to Oracle Wallet. Sample code below.

Errors

```
--
java.sql.SQLException: encountered a problem with the Secret Store. Check the wallet location for the presence of an open wallet (cwallet.sso) and ensure that this wallet contains the correct credentials using the mkstore utility: java.io.IOException: oracle.security.crypto.cert.PKCS12.getAuthSafesAsList()Ljava/util/ArrayList;
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.getSecretStoreCredentials(PhysicalConnection.java:1314)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.parseUrl(PhysicalConnection.java:1198)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.readConnectionProperties(PhysicalConnection.java:982)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:646)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:428)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:38)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
```

--

### Sample Code

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
     System.out.println("-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------");

        try {

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }

        System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");

        Connection connection = null;
        determineAndSetTnsHome();

        try {

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:/@xxx");

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }

        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
        }
    }
private static void determineAndSetTnsHome() {
    String tnsAdmin = System.getenv("TNS_ADMIN");
    if (tnsAdmin == null) {
        String oracleHome = System.getenv("ORACLE_HOME");
        if (oracleHome == null) {
            return; //failed to find any useful env variables            
        }
        tnsAdmin = oracleHome + File.separatorChar + "network" + File.separatorChar + "admin";
    }

    System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin", tnsAdmin);
}
```

--

### Notes

Confirmed that wallet is setup. 
- Doing sqlplus $xxx connects fine.

### - Doing mkstore -wrl  -listCredential  returns the entry after entering wallet password.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You nee to debug to find out what is happening.  Maybe you are returning here `return; //failed to find any useful env variables`

Answer (score 1):

Can you check out the [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/ssl-connection-to-oracle-db-using-jdbc%2C-tlsv12%2C-jks-or-oracle-wallets) for more details? 
Check if you are using TLSv1.2 and Oracle Wallets require additional jars (oraclepki.jar, osdt_core.jar, and osdt_cert.jar)

Answer (score 0):

Your wallet may be installed and configured correctly, but that does not mean the wallet is currently open. Anytime the database is restarted, the wallet needs to be opened.

Run a sample query against a known table in your schema in SQL*Plus (connecting is not enough)

If the wallet is not open you will get the following error:

> ORA-28365: wallet is not open

This query should give you the status of the wallet:

```
select wrl_type wallet,status,wrl_parameter wallet_location from v$encryption_wallet;
```

In order to open a wallet, run the following command, replacing "myPassword" with the password you chose:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET ENCRYPTION WALLET OPEN IDENTIFIED BY "myPassword";
```